# can database integrity check be run per table?

Tags: database, sqlite

As above, `PRAGMA INTEGRITY_CHECK` works on the entire database, can it, under any condition work on table basis?

(in reference to SQLite3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `PRAGMA integrity_check(\<TABLENAME\>).`